# Query to fetch user names according to a condition from another table (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

user

| id | full_name | is_admin | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alan | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Carl | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Any | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | Jane | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | Marry | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | Pedri | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | admin | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | Mota | 0 | 0 |

approver

| id | subordinate_id | leader_id | main_leader_id | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 0 |

(subordinate_id, leader_id and main_leader_id are foreign keys that correspond to the id column of the user table)

I would like to perform a query that brings all user names that are not admin (user table is_admin=0) and that are active (user table is_active=1), and that if they have the id in the subordinate_id column in the approver table that only brings the name of that user that has the is_active of the approver table = 0.

That is, I would like to bring users that if they have any record as subordinate_id that only bring me those that are not active in the approver table.

I tried to get the data in the following way:

```
 SELECT 
      full_name 
    FROM user AS U 
    LEFT JOIN approver AS A 
    ON U.id = A.subordinate_id 
    WHERE 
      A.id is null 
    AND 
      U.is_admin = 0 
    AND 
      U.is_active = 1
```

But with this query i only get the user name that not has a register in the approver table,
and in my case i want to get the user that have a register in the approver table as subordinate_id, but not if the register have the column 'is_active' equal to 1.

In my final result I could get something like this:

Alan
carl
any
marry
Pedri

Comment: MySql and tsql are conflicting technologies, please re-tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make this working, you should split the conditions in the `WHERE` clause into:

- "*user*" conditions: `is_admin = 0` AND `is_active = 1`
- "*approver*" conditions: is not a subordinate OR `is_active = 0`

These two groups of conditions have to be set in AND.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_.id, user_.full_name 
FROM      user_
LEFT JOIN approver
       ON user_.id = approver.subordinate_id
WHERE (user_.is_admin = 0 AND user_.is_active = 1) 
  AND (approver.id IS NULL OR approver.is_active = 0)
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u28CwUTBmHiEBtPgANk8Gf/0).

**Note**: the `DISTINCT` keyword is necessary because the `JOIN` operation is made between two tables having cardinality 1:n.

Comment: This works very good, thank you!